# How do you set more then 2 lines in a listView?

Tags: android, listview

I have created a simple forum in my app. If a user posts a question more then 2 lines I want to be able to display it in my custom listview. Even if I try to set android:maxLines="7" it refuses to show more then 2 lines? How do I fix this? Havnt been able to find any answer to this problem.... This is my xml code:

Edit: The problem occurs in the TextView (android:id="@+id/feedback_list_item_comment") where the users comment is displayed in the listView...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:background="@drawable/rowselector"

    >

    <TableRow
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedback_list_item_name"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.46"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="0.5"
        android:text="Unknown"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedback_list_item_time"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.46"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:text="dd.mm.yy"
        android:textColor="#3c6dae"
        android:textSize="14dp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedback_list_item_replies"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"

        > 
        </TextView>
```

This is the comment TextView below where I want to set the number of lines to 7....:

```
<TableRow>

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedback_list_item_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:shadowColor="#bdbebd"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:shadowRadius="1.0"
        android:text="No comment"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="12dp"
       >            
        </TextView>    

</TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: By using custom adapter for ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted enough code to tell, but I bet you are using the standard two line list view from the Android library.  If you want to have full control over the appearance of list view items, you will need to make custom views and extend `ArrayAdapter<...>` with a custom adapter to load them.

I was intimidated by this the first time I did it, but it's really not that much work and you will find that having control over your ListView is well worth the time.

Here is a link to get you started: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429